# Please connect my Academia account to the rest of my logins

Tags: support, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I attempted to answer just one question on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/how-should-i-cite-something-learned-second-hand-eg-from-wikipedia-when-i-have/7788#7788) and just manually entered my name, email address and web site instead of logging in.

(In hindsight I strongly suggest people *not* do that, and, in fact, if the site can sniff cookies or whatever suggesting an existing stackexchange login is available I suggest it should say "are you sure" rather than just start a new login with a password request waiting.)

So it partially created a [login](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/5930/mark-hurd) that has 10 points because someone upvoted my answer almost immediately. I realised my mistake and tried to connect to my exist login. Instead I now have a New login called [user5931](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/5931/user5931) which doesn't have the 5 points need to put this request on their meta.

So, in summary, can I have my [manual Academia login](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/5930/mark-hurd) connected to my stackexchange profile (which probably means merging with [this account](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/5931/user5931), but I'm not sure because it has not received the 100 point linked account reputation, if it is meant to be provided.

Comment: You need to ask this on [Meta Academia](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com) so the moderators there can merge the two accounts.

Comment: Follow the instructions here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Comment: @animuson As Mark notes, he can't post on the Academia meta since his new account doesn't have the required 5 rep.

Comment: FYI I have now successfully submitted the form at the bottom of help/user-merge but I couldn't edit my "About me" because there's another account with the same email address! (Yes, that's the one I want to keep, but the password recovery returns to the other one...) The help/user-merge form returned a "oops" page the first and second time I tried it. Doing a full refresh of the page allowed it to succeed.